# No signature of method: org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.destinationDir()

Tags: android-studio

I'm getting this error

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not create task ':app:packLibsflutterBuildDebug'.
> > No signature of method: org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.destinationDir() is applicable for argument types: (File) values: [/Users/amjadkhoulani/Downloads/food_app12amjad/build/app/intermediates/flutter/debug]

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.5.0'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.10, 0.99.99]'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    defaultConfig {
        // Required by the Flutter WebView plugin.
        minSdkVersion 21
    }
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.food_app"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            manifestPlaceholders = [applicationName: "android.app.Application"]
        }

        debug {
            manifestPlaceholders = [applicationName: "android.app.Application"]
        }
        build{
            manifestPlaceholders = [applicationName: "android.app.Application"]
        }
    }
}
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdk 33
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.abc.test"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: "kotlin-android-extensions"

androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}

apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"


flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.3.0')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[4.0.0, 4.99.99]'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:33'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
```

......................

Answer (score 9):

Flutter 3.7.11 doesn't work with Gradle 8. These were the highest versions I could get working:

**android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript { 
  ext.kotlin_version='1.7.10'...
}
dependencies {
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
  ...
}
```

**android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properies:**

```
...
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.1-all.zip
```

Comment: Indeed you need at least Flutter 3.7.12 to use Gradle 8: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/124838. But probably better to wait a bit until https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/125181 is fixed otherwise you may have build  issues due to 3rd party packages.

Comment: same here, gradle-7.6.1 version is the highest compatible as of now

Answer (score 4):

This can happen if your gradle dependencies are out of date or out of sync.

### android/build.gradle

Find the most recent, stable version of com.android.tools.build from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle?repo=google)  and update your dependencies:

```
dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1'
    }
```

### android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

Find the most recent stable version of Gradle from [here](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/) and update the distribution URL.

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-all.zip
```

Comment: not working for me after these changes any idea?